# Axiom of regularity from Terence Tao

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question concerning the two implications of the axiom of regularity given in the third edition of Analysis I by Terence Tao. I am aware this question has been raised before but there only one of the implications of the axiom of regularity has been been included. The statement of axiom 3.9 gives:

> **Axiom 3.9** (Regularity). If A is non-empty set, then there is at least one element x of A which is "either not a set", or is disjoint from A.

I put the first requirement of in quotation marks as the implication of this definition is where I get confused. Exercise 3.2.2 reads:

> Exercise 3.2.2. Use the axiom of regularity (and the singleton set axiom) to show that if $A$ is a set, then $A \notin A$ Furthermore show that if A and B are two sets, then either $A\notin B$ or $B\notin A$ (or both).

The first part of the exercise is the part I want clarified. I have already shown that if $A$ contains an element, $x$ disjoint from $A$, then this implies that $A \notin A$ as a consequence of $A \cap \{A\} = \emptyset$, but I am unsure how the presence of primitive objects (objects that aren't sets) in the set, $A$ implies the same result. Every source I have found doesn't include this discussion of primitive objects in the axiom of regularity and only states that there is an object, $x$, disjoint from $A$. I would appreciate any help with understanding this, thank you.

P.S. Apologies if I have got any of the terminology wrong, I am a physics student, not a mathematician.

Comment: Your argument still works, because we are assuming by hypothesis in exercise 3.2.2 that $A$ is a set. To flesh this out; since $A$ is a set, so is $\{A\}$, and so by the axiom of regularity, the set $\{A\}$ contains an element that is either (a) not a set, or (b) disjoint from $\{A\}$. The only element of $\{A\}$ is $A$, which is by hypothesis a set, so (a) cannot apply and hence we must have $A\cap\{A\}=\emptyset$ as desired.

Comment: This could just be an answer, @AtticusStonestrom :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I think I get this now, the first part of the axiom ensures that primitive objects can exist within set say A = {1,{1,2}} but as the A and {1,2} are not disjoint this needs to be stated separately and shown using the second argument that this does not lead to self contained sets, is that correct? Thank you!

Comment: Also @SK19 I am unsure what you mean by, "This could just be an answer".

Comment: @KristianStokkereit so sorry, but I don't quite understand what you're saying. all that the axiom of regularity says is that, if $A$ is a non-empty set, then either $A$ contains a primitive element or $A$ contains a non-primitive element that is disjoint from itself

Comment: in the case of the example of $A$ that you give, then $A\ni 1$, and so since $1$ is a primitive element $A$ thus satisfies the axiom of regularity

Comment: I think you might be confused about what the axiom of regularity is saying. it says that, for any non empty set $A$, (at least) one of the following two things holds: (a) $A$ contains a primitive element, or (b) $A$ contains an element $B\in A$ such that $B$ is a set and $A\cap B=\emptyset$

Comment: the example set $A=\{1, \{1, 2\}\}$ that you give is a non-empty set, and it does *not* satisfy condition (b) (indeed, the only set $B$ such that $B\in A$ is $\{1, 2\}$, which is not disjoint from $A$, since $A\cap B=\{1\}$). however, $A$ *does* satisfy condition (a), since $1\in A$ is a primitive element, and so $A$ does obey the axiom of regularity, since the axiom of regularity requires only that $A$ satisfy *one* of the two conditions, not both

Comment: Rereading your question, I think I might see your confusion. In the proof of the first part of the exercise, we are applying the axiom of regularity to the non-empty set $\{A\}$. This set contains *only one* element (namely $A$), and this element is not primitive (since $A$ is assumed to be a set, and hence is not primitive). Thus, no matter what, $\{A\}$ does not contain any primitive elements. It doesn't matter what elements $A$ contains or how many primitive elements $A$ contains; these are not themselves elements of $\{A\}$, which contains *only* the element $A$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I thought your comment provided a meaningful and complete answer to the question and i was encouraging you to post it as that.

Comment: @SK19 thanks! :) will do if you think it's worthwhile! depending on what OP says.

Comment: @SK19 oh I think the comment you might be responding to was one that OP made, not me...

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Sorry it took me a while to respond to this. My confusion was why the presence of a primitive element would indicate that the A is not self containing, I already understood why a disjoint non-primitive element would indicate that A is not self containing but I didn't understand why the condition could the lack of a disjoint element but a primitive element instead would fulfil the condition but I now I understand . I was merely using the above set as an example.

Comment: Also I agree with @SK19, your answer was very well explained and might be good for anyone else who is interested. Definitely worthy of an upvote.